# Custom javascript files not compiling in app.js with Zurb Foundation and Zurb Template

Tags: javascript, npm, zurb-foundation

From what I can gather on this page of the docs (https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#javascript-compilation) it sounds like I can put a custom javascript file in src/assets/javascript and it will get compiled in app.js. However, that is not working for me. My custom .js file simply does not get put into app.js. Any ideas why? This is just a straight up fresh install of Foundation 6.4.3 and using the Zurb Template.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I just require instead of import so in my app.js I put:

```
require('./your-custom-js');
```

and it compiles with no issues.

Comment: Yeah.. it compiles but it breaks just about every single library/plugin I use. Not having any luck with moment.js right now.